# What does |= mean in python?

Tags: python

What does the `|=` operator mean in python?

I came across this `|=` operator in a recursive function: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet-pysrc.html#Synset.hypernym_distances

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it's a `set` operator, which updates the set. From the documentation:

```
Update the set, adding elements from all others.
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation is misleading here. Calling the `.update()` method on a `set` doesn't return anything, it mutates the `set` in-place.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The documentation for the built-in type [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) is correct. Only the documentation of the *old and deprecated* `sets` module is incorrect.

Comment: Incidentally, this answer links to the wrong documentation.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Indeed, I hadn't even noticed that this wasn't the  builtin doc.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, `x |= y` is shorthand for `x = x | y` (although there are subtleties that mean the two forms are not strictly equivalent).

Read more about this in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-augmented_assignment_stmt).

In the example you quote, `|=` is used to add elements to a set. This usage is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> `update(other, ...)`
>
> `set |= other | ...`
>
> Update the set, adding elements from all others.

Comment: I wonder who went through and downvoted all but one of the answers. There's nothing downvote-worthy here.

Comment: @user2357112 same with my answer below :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a printout of python build-in interactive help (`help()` function, it's pretty neat!)

```
help> |=

Augmented assignment statements
*******************************

Augmented assignment is the combination, in a single statement, of a
binary operation and an assignment statement:

   augmented_assignment_stmt ::= augtarget augop (expression_list | yield_expression)
   augtarget                 ::= identifier | attributeref | subscription | slicing
   augop                     ::= "+=" | "-=" | "*=" | "/=" | "//=" | "%=" | "**="
             | ">>=" | "<<=" | "&=" | "^=" | "|="

(See section *Primaries* for the syntax definitions for the last three
symbols.)

An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal
assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression
list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment
on the two operands, and assigns the result to the original target.
The target is only evaluated once.
An augmented assignment expression like ``x += 1`` can be rewritten as
``x = x + 1`` to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In
the augmented version, ``x`` is only evaluated once. Also, when
possible, the actual operation is performed *in-place*, meaning that
rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target,
the old object is modified instead.

With the exception of assigning to tuples and multiple targets in a
single statement, the assignment done by augmented assignment
statements is handled the same way as normal assignments. Similarly,
with the exception of the possible *in-place* behavior, the binary
operation performed by augmented assignment is the same as the normal
binary operations.

For targets which are attribute references, the same *caveat about
class and instance attributes* applies as for regular assignments.
(END)
```

Answer (score 1):

`|=` means `Union` when used on sets,

```
s1 = set([4,3,7])
s2 = set([0,2,1])
s1 |= s3

>> {0, 1, 3, 4, 7}
```

The result contains unique values because of the nature of set(holds unique items)

Answer (score -1):

A |= B
is identical to:
A = A | B

Comment: This is not correct. `|=` calls `__ior__`, mutating `A` if possible, whereas `|` calls `__or__` and `=` rebinds `A` to the resulting new object.

Comment: I see it's a gotcha! (Thanks for the prompt correction!)